# utc+2 getutcdate() - getdate() difference is wrong

Tags: sql, timezone, getdate

i am in turkey. turkey timezone is (UTC +02:00)

But on sql server management studio

```
select (GETDATE() - GETUTCDATE() ) as a
```

gives

1900-01-01 03:00:00.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turkey is currently on daylight saving time.  It uses UTC+03:00 until October 27, when it will switch back to UTC+02:00.  [Details here](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/clockchange.html?n=107&year=2013).

Your *standard* time zone offset is +2, but your *current* offset is +3.  Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".